# Scrapy raises ReactorNotRestartable when CrawlerProcess is ran twice

Tags: python, scrapy, twisted, pytest

I have some code which looks something like this:

```
def run(spider_name, settings):
    runner = CrawlerProcess(settings)
    runner.crawl(spider_name)
    runner.start()
    return True
```

I have two py.test tests which each call run(), when the second test executes I get the following error.

```
    runner.start()
../../.virtualenvs/scrape-service/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py:291: in start
    reactor.run(installSignalHandlers=False)  # blocking call
../../.virtualenvs/scrape-service/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py:1242: in run
    self.startRunning(installSignalHandlers=installSignalHandlers)
../../.virtualenvs/scrape-service/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py:1222: in startRunning
    ReactorBase.startRunning(self)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor object at 0x10fe21588>

    def startRunning(self):
        """
            Method called when reactor starts: do some initialization and fire
            startup events.

            Don't call this directly, call reactor.run() instead: it should take
            care of calling this.

            This method is somewhat misnamed.  The reactor will not necessarily be
            in the running state by the time this method returns.  The only
            guarantee is that it will be on its way to the running state.
            """
        if self._started:
            raise error.ReactorAlreadyRunning()
        if self._startedBefore:
>           raise error.ReactorNotRestartable()
E           twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable
```

I get this reactor thing is already running so I cannot `runner.start()` when the second test runs. But is there some way to reset its state inbetween the tests? So they are more isolated and actually can run after one another.

Comment: Are you testing whether the crawls run or do you need something from the crawls for your tests?

Comment: from the crawls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [`CrawlerRunner`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/api.html#scrapy.crawler.CrawlerRunner) instead of `CrawlerProcess` in conjunction with [`pytest-twisted`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-twisted), you should be able to use run your tests like this:

Install Twisted integration for Pytest: `pip install pytest-twisted`

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner

def _run_crawler(spider_cls, settings):
    """
    spider_cls: Scrapy Spider class
    settings: Scrapy settings
    returns: Twisted Deferred
    """
    runner = CrawlerRunner(settings)
    return runner.crawl(spider_cls)     # return Deferred


def test_scrapy_crawler():
    deferred = _run_crawler(MySpider, settings)

    @deferred.addCallback
    def _success(results):
        """
        After crawler completes, this function will execute.
        Do your assertions in this function.
        """

    @deferred.addErrback
    def _error(failure):
        raise failure.value

    return deferred
```

To put it plainly, `_run_crawler()` will schedule a crawl in the Twisted reactor and execute callbacks when the scrape completes. In those callbacks (`_success()` and `_error()`) is where you will do your assertions. Lastly, you have to return the `Deferred` object from `_run_crawler()` so that the test waits until the crawl is complete. This part with the `Deferred`, is essential and must be done for all tests.

Here's an example of how to run multiple crawls and aggregate results using [`gatherResults`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/defer.html#gatherresults).

```
from twisted.internet import defer

def test_multiple_crawls():
    d1 = _run_crawler(Spider1, settings)
    d2 = _run_crawler(Spider2, settings)

    d_list = defer.gatherResults([d1, d2])

    @d_list.addCallback
    def _success(results):
        assert True

    @d_list.addErrback
    def _error(failure):
        assert False

    return d_list
```

I hope this helps, if it doesn't please ask where you're struggling.

Answer (score 2):

[According to the scrapy docs:](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#running-multiple-spiders-in-the-same-process)

> By default, Scrapy runs a single spider per process when you run
>   scrapy crawl. However, Scrapy supports running multiple spiders per
>   process using the internal API.

For example:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class MySpider1(scrapy.Spider):
    # Your first spider definition
    ...

class MySpider2(scrapy.Spider):
    # Your second spider definition
    ...

process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(MySpider1)
process.crawl(MySpider2)
process.start() # the script will block here until all crawling jobs are finished
```

If you want to run another spider after you've called `process.start` then I expect you can just issue another `process.crawl(SomeSpider)` call at the point in your program where you determine the need to do this.

Examples of other scenarios are given [in the docs](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#running-multiple-spiders-in-the-same-process).

Comment: the docs, nor that example show me how to run a crawler process twice in one process, in order to test different things. looks like i'll have to just mock this out as these global instances are a mess

Comment: That's exactly what it shows.  Call `crawl` multiple times and `start` only once.