# Scrapy Splash crawler ReactorNotRestartable

Tags: python, scrapy, twisted, scrapy-splash

I've developed a Scrapy Splash scraper using Visual Studio Code on Windows 10.

When I run my scraper like so without a `runner.py` file it works and generates the scraped content int "out.json": `scrapy crawl mytest -o out.json`

However, when I run the scraper (either in debug mode in Visual Studio code with this `runner.py` file it fails on the `execute` line (full code below):

```
Exception has occurred: ReactorNotRestartable
exception: no description
  File "C:\scrapy\hw_spiders\spiders\runner.py", line 8, in <module>
    execute(
```

I already checked here:

- [Scrapy - Reactor not Restartable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41495052/scrapy-reactor-not-restartable)
- [Scrapy raises ReactorNotRestartable when CrawlerProcess is ran twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48913525/scrapy-raises-reactornotrestartable-when-crawlerprocess-is-ran-twice)
- [ReactorNotRestartable error in while loop with scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39946632/reactornotrestartable-error-in-while-loop-with-scrapy)

From those posts, it seems an issue if I start the 2nd scraper (e.g. "call crawl multiple times and start only once"), however, I don't see where I supposedly do that.

I also read there that there are potential issues with `while` loops and the `Twisted reactor`, but those too I don't see in my code.

So I'm now lost as to where I need to fix my code.

**runner.py**

```
#https://newbedev.com/debugging-scrapy-project-in-visual-studio-code
import os
from scrapy.cmdline import execute

os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))

try:
    execute(
        [
            'scrapy',
            'crawl',
            'mytest',
            '-o',
            'out.json',
        ]
    )
except SystemExit:
    pass
```

**launch.json**

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Launch Scrapy Spider",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "scrapy",
            "args": [
                "runspider",
                "${file}"
            ],
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

**settings.json**

```
{
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
        "./hw_spiders"
    ]
}
```

**middlewares.py**

```
from scrapy import signals
from itemadapter import is_item, ItemAdapter

class MySpiderMiddleware:

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        s = cls()
        crawler.signals.connect(s.spider_opened, signal=signals.spider_opened)
        return s

    def process_spider_input(self, response, spider):
        return None

    def process_spider_output(self, response, result, spider):
        for i in result:
            yield i

    def process_spider_exception(self, response, exception, spider):
        pass

    def process_start_requests(self, start_requests, spider):
        for r in start_requests:
            yield r

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        spider.logger.info('Spider opened: %s' % spider.name)


class MyDownloaderMiddleware:

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        s = cls()
        crawler.signals.connect(s.spider_opened, signal=signals.spider_opened)
        return s

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        return None

    def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
        return response

    def process_exception(self, request, exception, spider):
        pass

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        spider.logger.info('Spider opened: %s' % spider.name)
```

**pipelines.py**

```
from itemadapter import ItemAdapter


class MyPipeline:
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        return item
```

**settings.py**

```
BOT_NAME = 'hw_spiders'
SPIDER_MODULES = ['hw_spiders.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'hw_spiders.spiders'
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True

SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware': 100,
    # 'hw_spiders.middlewares.MySpiderMiddleware': 543,
}

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    # 'hw_spiders.middlewares.MyDownloaderMiddleware': 543,
    'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware': 723,
    'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware': 725,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 810,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
    'scrapy_useragents.downloadermiddlewares.useragents.UserAgentsMiddleware': 500,
} 

SPLASH_URL = 'http://localhost:8050/' 
DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter'
HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareFSCacheStorage'
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False
```

**mytest.py**

```
import json
import re
import os

import scrapy
import time
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse

from ..myitems import CarItem

class MyTest_Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'mytest'
    start_urls = ['<hidden>']

    def start_requests(self):
        yield SplashRequest(
            self.start_urls[0], self.parse
        )

    def parse(self, response):
        object_links = response.css('div.wrapper div.inner33 > a::attr(href)').getall()

        for link in object_links:
            yield scrapy.Request(link, self.parse_object)

        next_page = response.css('div.nav-links a.next.page-numbers::attr(href)').get()
        if next_page is not None:
            next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)


    def parse_object(self, response):
        item = RentalItem()

        item['url'] = response.url

        object_features = response.css('table.info tr')
        for feature in object_features:
            try:
                feature_title = feature.css('th::text').get().strip()
                feature_info = feature.css('td::text').get().strip()
            except:
                continue
        item['thumbnails'] = response.css("ul#objects li a img::attr(src)").getall()
```

**UPDATE 1**

So I now removed runner.py from my project and just have the .vscode\launch.json:

[image]

When I open my file `mytest.py` in Visual Studio Code and hit F5 to debug, I see the following output:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\scrapy\hw_spiders>  & 'C:\Users\Adam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe' 'c:\Users\Adam\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.11.1422169775\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\launcher' '51812' '--' '-m' 'scrapy' 'runspider' 'c:\scrapy\hw_spiders\spiders\mytest.py'
2021-11-19 14:19:02 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.3.0 started (bot: hw_spiders)
2021-11-19 14:19:02 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.5.2.0, libxml2 2.9.5, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 20.3.0, Python 3.8.5 (tags/v3.8.5:580fbb0, Jul 20 2020, 
15:43:08) [MSC v.1926 32 bit (Intel)], pyOpenSSL 19.1.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020), cryptography 3.0, Platform Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
2021-11-19 14:19:02 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor
Usage
=====
  scrapy runspider [options] <spider_file>

runspider: error: Unable to load 'c:\\scrapy\\hw_spiders\\spiders\\mytest.py': attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

This must be line `from ..myitems import RentalItem`, but I don't know why this fails.

Answer (score 0):

You should *either* create a `runner.py` file and use the default Python `launch.json` configuration to run the `runner.py` file, OR *not* have a `runner.py` file and use the `scrapy` `launch.json` (as in your question) - not both.

It looks like the [article](https://newbedev.com/debugging-scrapy-project-in-visual-studio-code) in your question just copied all of the answers from [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49201915/debugging-scrapy-project-in-visual-studio-code) and combined them without context.

Comment: Ah, thanks! What are the pros and cons of runner.py vs launch.json? A Google search doesn't return anything on it. Also, I've added update 1 with my latest test, would you please have a look?